# unable to know the use of the statement "(void) ipAddr; (void) port;" in Iotivity framework

Tags: c, casting, iotivity

i was working on Iotivity framework, while tracing i was not able to know the use of these statements.
iotivity-1.3.0/resource/csdk/stack/src/ocstack.c

i'm curious to know the usage...

```
OCStackResult OCInit(const char *ipAddr, uint16_t port, OCMode mode)
{
(void) ipAddr;
(void) port;
return OCInit1(mode, OC_DEFAULT_FLAGS, OC_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code

```
(void) ipAddr;
(void) port;
```

is a way to silence compiler warning about "unused" variables.

It comes handy when the APIs has to follow a certain pattern to accept a number of parameters to conform to some standard, but actually, in the code you do not use the variables anyway.

Comment: In this case, a look at the documentation should clarify, there were once used but no longer: 

    `ipAddr IP Address of host device. Deprecated parameter. `
    `port Port of host device. Deprecated parameter.`